# Is there any terminal tool to convert from ODT to PDF/PS?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

There is *unoconv* for Linux.
I am looking something similar for Mac.
I think no such a program exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unoconv's [gitHub page](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/README.asciidoc) is stated that:

> LibreOffice 3.6.0.1 or later is required to use unoconv under MacOS X. This is the first version distributed with an internal python script that works.

There it's explained too, how to install it.

And being the latest version of LibreOffice [v4.0.1](http://www.libreoffice.org/download), there should be no problem with it.

Comment: Github page for unoconv is https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv